# how to check if a path is well formed with FsCheck in FSharp

Tags: f#, nuget-package, fscheck

I'm struggling getting an answer to this:

Define a function `functionWF` and `functionPath` that takes an FsTree and returns a boolean that check whether the given tree is well-formed as a filesystem and whether the path (represented as a list of strings) is well-formed.

A well-formed filesystem cannot have identical paths leading to different nodes in the tree.

A well-formed path cannot contain nodes with empty names.

bellow a the type `FsTree = Node of (string * FsTree) list`

and bellow is an example of a FsTree :

```
fsT = [Node ("f1", [Node ("f2", [])]); [Node ("f3", [])]]
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow :) You've defined your problem well, which is great :) could you please provide the code which you have so far, along with a description or example of 1.) what it's currently doing 2.) what you want it to be doing, and 3.) what you've tried to fix it, so far

Answer (score 1):

A `Node` is ill-formed if it contains more than one element with the same name, or if that is the case for any of the subtrees that it contains. Specifically, `Node []` is well-formed. Those concepts can be the cases the recursive function `functionWF`:

```
let rec functionWF (tree : FsTree) : bool =
    match tree with 
    | Node [] -> true
    | Node list -> 
        let strings = List.map fst list
        let trees = List.map snd list
        let namesOk = allElementsUnique strings
        let subtreeOk state tree = state && (functionWF tree)
        List.fold subtreeOk namesOk trees
```

where `allElementsUnique` is a function that ensures that there are no duplicate elements in a list.

I don't understand what you mean that `functionPath` should do.

PS. Your example of an `FsTree` is not valid, it should have `Node` outside of the list:

```
let fsT = Node [("f1", Node [("f2", Node [])]); ("f3", Node [])]
```